Database Modelling in PowerBI creates ambiguity between three tables
I have three tables that all need to be connected, however this creates an ambiguous relationship between the tables. I understand why that happens. However, I cannot think of the solution to my problem of connecting all three tables.
In the attached image I made a simplified version of the database model. The MaterialData table contains information that is required to supplement the production orders. The Departments table is used to determine what department the production order was in. For future prediction of capacity I want to know what the default line is for a material (the forecast numbers are attached to MaterialData table).
Furthermore, I have a line chart that shows past production and future forecast per department.
Database Relationship Model

I thought of and tried different set-ups of the data model.
I am expecting that I can use the Departments table to filer both Production Orders table and the MaterialData table. And the Production Orders table can still access the article information in MaterialData.
Edit:
Added some screenshots of the data in the tables:
MaterialData Table

Departments Table

ProductionOrders Table


Can you provide data example?

@RADO Data example: MaterialData.Material = "1000001420" with DefaultLine "PKG-08". Departments.Machine = "PKG-08" is in department "Packaging" and Sub-Department "Packing". Production Orders contains material "1000001420" but for example it was produced on line "PKG-07".
